# Connecting to SQL Server 2005 using 127.0.0.1\INSTNAME stops working if SQL Server 2008 is installed on the same machine

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have an application that connects to a named SQL Server 2005 Express instance using 127.0.0.1\INSTNAME. This has always worked. However, if I install SQL Server 2008 (any edition) on the same machine, the application can no longer connect to the SQL Server 2005 instance using 127.0.0.1. I tried connecting using SQL Management Studio and it too could not make a connection using 127.0.0.1. I then tried .\INSTNAME and that worked. Changing the application to use .\INSTNAME is not an option at present.

Does anybody have a workaround for this issue. It doesn't have to be permanent since the application in question is an installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to check

- Make sure TCP/IP is enabled (I'm going to assume this is not the problem)
- Make sure the SQL Server Browser service is running on your server (this is probably the problem

Comment: The SQL Server Browser service wasn't running. Our application installs SQL Server Express 2005 and it usually installs the browser service and starts it. But I guess since a newer version of the browser service was already installed, it didn't have to install the browser component and thus didn't enable and start the browser service.